# Android App communicating with the BBC Micro:Bit

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, bbc-microbit

Im trying to write an Android app that connects to and communicates with a BBC Micro:bit board.
I'm writing the application using Xamarin (C#) and i've got a few things working already (Scanning for BLE devices and connecting to the Micro:Bit).

The hurdle i'm facing at the moment is getting access to and retrieving data from the IO Pin Service.

This seems to be quite easy in C/C++ but i can't find any examples on how it's done in Xamarin/C#.

I have no idea how that is done and i would really appreciate any tips or pointers anyone might have.
Thanks!